# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './test.md' when using gray-matter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

My app directory looks like this:

- page.js [current file]
- layout.js
- test.md

This is the code from my page.js page

```
import matter from "gray-matter";

export default function Home() {
  const data = matter.read("./test.md");
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <>
      {/* {data} */}
      <h1>hello world</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

However i get the Error: `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './test.md'` error what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You said you had `text.md`, but the program tries to access `test.md`

Comment: @ikegami my bad the file is called test.md just typed it wrong error still there

Comment: This is a `node` program? My guess is that is that paths are relative to the current work directory, and the the current work directory isn't what you think it is. You assume it's the directory in which the files are located, but that's a bad assumption. In pseuso code, you normally have to do something like `dir = dirname( realpath( prog_path ) )`. (No real experience with `node`, and never even heard of gray-matter. Just a common programming bug in general. But `node` surely has a function to obtain the CWD, so you could easily check if this is possibly the problem.)